# How to use listview inside a listview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

How can I use a listview inside a listview ie(Nested Listview) while using seperate model class inside both of the listviews that use indexes?[Eg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CT6f.png)

Comment: just use "shrinkWrap : true"

Comment: What will be scroll behavior, do they scroll separately or use the same scroll event.

Comment: They will use the same scroll event.You can think of this as an orders page in an ecommerce website.The first listview is for orderID and the sub-listview is for products .So as in one order ID can have multiple products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to below code example

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCnFv.jpg)

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 2,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                "List View 1 | Index : $index",
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: 5,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
                    trailing: const Text(
                      "Text",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      "List View 2 | Index Val: $index",
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

add `shrinkWrap: true` in inner Listview